# How can one method be called multiply and simultaneously?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, button

I am developing an iOS app with swift. In this app, an interface like the keyboard of a piano must be implemented. I want to make this keyboard polyphonic one, which means this keyboard is able to be tapped simultaneously, but I still have not succeded.

I examined the timestamp of handling button-tapped event. The handle method is below.

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       for touch in touches {
           let point = touch.location(in: self.stackView)
           let hitView = self.stackView.hitTest(point, with: event)
           if (hitView != nil) {
               NSLog("%d first", hitView!.tag)
               self.pushChanged(senderTag: hitView!.tag, add: true)
               self.keyPushed(senderTag: hitView!.tag, userPushed: true)
               self.keyboardTouchStateChanged(senderTag: hitView!.tag, add: true)
               if self.bluetoothTag == "1" {
                   let data = String(hitView!.tag)
                   self.bService.send(colorName: data)
               }
               NSLog("%d last", hitView!.tag)
           }
       }
   }
func keyPushed(senderTag:Int, userPushed:Bool = false){
       audioPlayers[senderTag].currentTime = 0
       audioPlayers[senderTag].play()
   }
```

And the timestamp is below.

```
2019-08-09 20:48:24.878297+0900 ***[31982:2052909] 40 first
2019-08-09 20:48:24.906382+0900 ***[31982:2052909] 40 last
2019-08-09 20:48:24.906604+0900 ***[31982:2052909] 52 first
2019-08-09 20:48:24.930185+0900 ***[31982:2052909] 52 last
```

In this examination, I tapped the two buttons tagged with 40 and 52 respectively. As you can see in the log, firstly the event of 40-tag button is handled, and after it finished, that of 52-tag button is handled.

Here, I want these two (and more) event handlings to be executed simultaneously. I easily came up with implementing async execution. I tried DispatchQueue but did not work because the one function has to be executed asynchronously (need to be replicated?).

How can I implement this? Please show me some solution.

Comment: Add the gesture recognizers to a custom view (your keys)

Comment: Don't use tags with views. It is an old way of getting views. Use IBOutlets or Collection.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for your comment. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: @JayLee Thank you for your comment. Actually I replaced the IBOutlets and IBOutlets to UIView because their response was too slow. But I'll see if IBOutlets or Collection can solve this problem.